# I need to keep user's data in form fields after redirection

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm writing simple carpark application for my assingment and one of the last things that I need to do is to keep user's data in form fields after it gets redirected. The redirection happens when spot that user wants to reserve is already taken.

I found out that you can do it using session but I can't it doesn't work the way I want because I can't retrieve the data.

Here's the method new in my Reservation Controller:

```php
/**
     * New action.
     *
     * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request    HTTP request
     * @param \App\Repository\ReservationRepository     $repository Reservation repository
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response HTTP response
     *
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\ORMException
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException
     *
     * @Route(
     *     "/new",
     *     methods={"GET", "POST"},
     *     name="reservation_new",
     * )
     */
    public function new(Request $request, ReservationRepository $repository): Response
    {
        $reservation = new Reservation();
        $form = $this->createForm(ReservationType::class, $reservation);
        $form->handleRequest($request);


        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            if ($repository->findOneBy(['spot' => $reservation->getSpot()])) {

//                $occupied_from = $form['occupied_from']->getData();
//                $occupied_to = $form['occupied_to']->getData();
//                $payment = $form['payment']->getData();
//                $spot = $form['spot']->getData();

                dump($request->request->get('reservation'));

//                $occupied_from = $this->session->get('occupied_from', []);
//                $occupied_to = $this->session->get('occupied_to', []);
//                $payment = $this->session->get('payment', []);
//                $spot = $this->session->get('spot', []);

//                if ($reservation->getOccupiedFrom() == )

                $this->addFlash('error', 'message.spot_taken');

                return $this->redirectToRoute('reservation_new');
            }

            $reservation->setClient($this->getUser());
            $repository->save($reservation);


            $this->addFlash('success', 'message.updated_successfully');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('reservation_index');

        }

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() && $reservation->getOccupiedFrom() < new \DateTime('now') ) {

            $this->addFlash('error', 'message.inconsistent_date');

        }

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() && $reservation->getOccupiedFrom() > $reservation->getOccupiedTo()) {

            $this->addFlash('error', 'message.inconsistent_date');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('reservation_new');
        }



        return $this->render(
            'reservation/new.html.twig',
            ['form' => $form->createView()]
        );
    }
```

And here's the form for Reservation:

```php
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder->add(
            'occupiedFrom',
            DateTimeType::class,
            [
                'widget' => 'choice',
                'label' => 'label.occupied_from',
                'placeholder' => [
                    'year' => 'Year', 'month' => 'Month', 'day' => 'Day',
                    'hour' => 'Hour', 'minute' => 'Minute', 'second' => 'Second',
                ],
                'data' => new\DateTime(),
                'attr' => ['min' => (new DateTime())->format('YYYY-mm-dd HH:ii:ss')]
            ]
        );

        $builder->add(
            'occupiedTo',
            DateTimeType::class,
            [
                'widget' => 'choice',
                'label' => 'label.occupied_to',
                'placeholder' => [
                    'year' => 'Year', 'month' => 'Month', 'day' => 'Day',
                    'hour' => 'Hour', 'minute' => 'Minute', 'second' => 'Second',
                ],
                'data' => new\DateTime(),
                'attr' => ['min' => (new DateTime())->format('YYYY-mm-dd HH:ii:ss')]
            ]
        );

        $builder->add(
            'payment',
            EntityType::class,
            [
                'class' => Payment::class,
                'choice_label' => function ($payment) {
                    return $payment->getType();
                },
                'label' => 'label.payment',
                'placeholder' => 'label.none',
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );

        $builder->add(
            'spot',
            EntityType::class,
            [
                'class' => Spot::class,
                'choice_label' => function($spot) {
                return $spot->getSpot();
                },
                'label' => 'label.spot',
                'placeholder' => 'label.none',
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );
```

There are 4 values I need to access: 'occupied_from' which is the starting date of the reservation, 'occupied_to' which is the ending date, 'payment' one of two ways of payment for the reservation and 'spot' which is the name of the spot.

Whatever I do, I always get the redirect but data is not saved. Thanks in advance from an unexperienced collegue.

Comment: Are you able to use JavaScript? There's a JavaScript plugin called JS Cookie, which makes storing data in cookies very easy. You would then check if the cookies exist, and if so, populate the fields with the data. You can also explore HTML web storage (probably sessionStorage). https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Why redirect at all? You are already in `reservation_new` and have the data, just render the the template with the errors.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use JavaScript. I found some ways to do that with JavaScript but we are told not to implement it.

Comment: @msg I use flashes to display errors because that's the way we were taught.

Comment: The flash will still be shown if you don't redirect if it's set. Just try removing the redirection and calling `render`, see if it works for you.

Comment: I... think it works! Thank you so much. Data finally stays at its place. You don't know how long it took me. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can send data to the route, like this:

```
    return $this->redirectToRoute(
        'reservation_new', 
        [
            'occupied_to' => $occupiedTo,
            //etc ...
        ],
        301
    );

//in the other side:
public function reservationNew(string $occupiedTo) // ...
```

Anyway, you can use the SessionInterface Component, in any Controller or Service, like this:

in controller (like @msg suggest in the comment below):

```
$session = $this->get('session');
```

or in a service:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;

//...

    public function __construct(SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

// ...

        //set:
        $this->session->set('form_data',  [
            'occupied_to' => $occupiedTo,
            //etc ...
        ]);

        //and get:
        $this->session->get('form_data', []); // with the second parameter you can set the default value, if the data doesnt exist in the session...
```

After that, you can rebuild the form, with optionsResolver, or you know, what you want

Comment: You don't need to inject `SessionInterface` into controllers (most of the time) because they inherit it from `AbstractController`. You can retrieve it using `$this->get('session')`.

Comment: Are you sure? --> https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#managing-the-session

Comment: Yes, [`AbstractController` implements `ServiceSubscriberInterface`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/f4f2fda81f5293d5fdef7fbc614ea527114757d5/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/AbstractController.php#L81) and one of the subscribed services is `SessionInterface` (tecnically they are nullable services, but..). That's an important point, it comes from `AbstractController`, not `ControllerTrait` so if you have a a custom controller not extending it **you do** need to inject it, hence my remark of "most of the time".